# How to name a vector variables in order it was set

Tags: r, vector

I create a palette with `RColorBrewer` and want to set names for the colors from the ordered factor vector. I get variables from a data frame with `variables <- unique(df$column)` so different columns give different number of variables

```
library(RColorBrewer)
variables <- c("PR", "PD", "C", "SD", "CR")#as example 
variables  <- ordered(variables, levels = c("C", "CR", "PR", "SD", "PD"))
test_pal <- brewer.pal(length(variables), "Accent"); names(test_pal) <- variables
```

and it assigns names to colors according to the 'original' sequence in the vector

```
> test_pal
       PR        PD         C        SD        CR 
"#7FC97F" "#BEAED4" "#FDC086" "#FFFF99" "#386CB0"
```

but I want in the order set, like this:

```
        C        CR        PR        SD        PD 
"#7FC97F" "#BEAED4" "#FDC086" "#FFFF99" "#386CB0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordered` will create an ordered factor variable, but it does not order your vector (it only sets an order in the levels). You have to `order` or `sort` the factor (not just the levels) when you assign the new names:

```r
names(test_pal) <- sort(variables)
#names(test_pal) <- variables[order(variables)]

#        C        CR        PR        SD        PD 
#"#7FC97F" "#BEAED4" "#FDC086" "#FFFF99" "#386CB0"
```